# Magento 2 - All CMS pages are with content blank

Tags: magento2, php, cms, cms-pages

In my server with: elasticsearch7, apache 2.4.29, mariaDB 10.4 and php 7.4 I imported my Magento 2.4.2 site.
Everything works correctly except for the CMS pages that have empty content and in fact the #maincontent div is empty.

I am attaching a screenshot of the problem:
[image]
*Content is empty but without errors of php*

I've looked at the log files but they don't return any errors.
Why?

It's like Magento doesn't load the CMS page object ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have experience with SQL you can check the database table and

select * from cms_page where identifier = 'your-page';

You can also check if the page layout was not overwritten. Look for files cms_index_index_your-page.xml

Finally you can debug the controller:

vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php

Good luck!

Comment: My CMS homepage exist and i can see the content in backend. Why is not loaded in my frontend? Thanks

Comment: Check whether CMS homepage is assigned to any block

Comment: The CMS homepage is assigned correctly from backend of Magento2. This issue is on every CMS page. I can see blocks but not the content of CMS pages...

Comment: Did you look over for customizations on cms_index_index.xml? Further that, do you have more store views that you could assign wrongly. Could you share the common configurations of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Sample Data in your magento project

Go to your Magento Root and run the following command

```
bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

After installing Sample Data run setup upgrade command and then clear cache

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: I don't want install sample data because i have my custom content in my cms homepage. For you why i can not see his content in frontend? thx

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE SOLUTION!!

The issue is when **`cms_page_view.xml`** is missing!

So i added **`cms_page_view.xml`** to **`/vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout`**

and works like a charm!

I hope it serves someone else :)